# Internal class and interfaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've been trying to work out whether this is possible, I have a class that I want to make internal, and call it from another class within the same .cs file.

Best way to explain it is to show you my code, I have tried nesting the 2 classes and other techniques such as making the class abstract but i cannot get it to work, or i do not know whether its even possible.

```
internal class DisplayWeatherAstronomy
{
   public string SunRise           { get; internal set; }
   public string SunSet            { get; internal set; }
   public string MoonRise          { get; internal set; }
   public string MoonSet           { get; internal set; }
} 

public class GetWeatherAstronomy : IGetWeatherAstronomy
{
   internal IEnumerable<DisplayWeatherAstronomy> WeatherAstronomy(string id)
   {
      // code removed

      return displayAstronomy;
   }
}
```

problem is using the Interface, as intellisense complains about internal `IEnumerable<>`

The code above is in a class library which is referenced from an mvc app

Any help would be appreciated

George

Sorry forgot to add error

```
Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Web.Domain.Weather.DisplayWeatherAstronomy>' is less accessible than method 'Web.Domain.Weather.GetWeatherAstronomy.WeatherAstronomy(string)'

Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Web.Domain.Weather.DisplayWeatherAstronomy>' is less accessible than method 'Web.Domain.Weather.IGetWeatherAstronomy.WeatherAstronomy(string)'
```

Interface code

```
public interface IGetWeatherAstronomy
{
   IEnumerable<DisplayWeatherAstronomy> WeatherAstronomy(string id);
}
```

Comment: "whether this is possible" Whether what is possible? What is the problem?

Comment: So what was your actual error message? Or what problem did you otherwise run into?

Comment: Added error message, my mistake forgot to add it

Comment: What is the accessibility of `IGetWeatherAstronomy`?

Comment: Perhaps I am misremembering but, doesn't VS default to `private` if you don't explicitly declare the access level?

Comment: Hi Brian, yes but if its private, i still get the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that potential consumers of that interface don't have enough visibility to see what is referenced by that interface.  The interface is public, but the return type of the method references a non-public type.  What you need is an internal interface instead:

```
internal interface IGetWeatherAstronomy
{
    IEnumerable<DisplayWeatherAstronomy> WeatherAstronomy(string id);
}
```

Then, the return value of the method has the same accessibility as the interface itself.  For the same reason, the method on the public `GetWeatherAstronomy` class has to also be internal.  But... if you do that, you'll still get an error:

> 'GetWeatherAstronomy' does not implement interface member 'IGetWeatherAstronomy()'. 'GetWeatherAstronomy.WeatherAstronomy()' cannot implement an interface member because it is not public.

That happens because interface methods are public, even if the interface as a whole is internal.  So, instead of making the method public or internal, use explicit interface implementation instead:

```
public class GetWeatherAstronomy : IGetWeatherAstronomy
{
    IEnumerable<DisplayWeatherAstronomy> IGetWeatherAstronomy.WeatherAstronomy(string id)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

That does mean you'll have to cast your object to the interface type before you can call the method: `((IGetWeatherAstronomy)getWeatherAstronomy).WeatherAstronomy(...)` instead of `getWeatherAstronomy.WeatherAstronomy(...)`.  But, at least that way everything stays internal -- the only way to get through the method is through the interface, and the only way to get to the interface is via internal accessibility.

Comment: Thanks Tadmas, i'm just having problem casting the interface in ninject, but thats another problem

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an access issue.

Does your interface define the WeatherAstronmy method? Inteface methods are by default public as they define contracts to be used in other assemblies, therefore having an internal method wouldn't make a huge amount of sense.

Comment: I was beginning to come to the conclusion that it could not be done, that was the reason I posted the question. Should have made it more clearer by adding the error message

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have declared the  IEnumerable< DisplayWeatherAstronomy > member on your IGetWeatherAstronomy interface.

Unfortunately this won't work. You can't declare internal members of interfaces.

You must either remove the member from the interface, or, make DisplayWeatherAstronomy a public class. Or refactor completely.

Comment: Hi Brendan, I have tried that, but then I get Inconsistent accessibility error with DisplayWeatherAstronomy within public class GetWeatherAstronomy.